# Перекинуть MenuItem.Header в стиль

Tags: c#, wpf

Хотелось бы сократить код, перекинув такой многострочный Header в стиль. Как я делал - работает только для одного элемента.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem" x:Key="MenuItemsStyle">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
    </Style>
 </Window.Resources>

<Menu Width="auto" Height="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="List">

                <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource MenuItemsStyle}">
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Width="100" Text="1 File................."/>
                            <TextBlock>23 августа</TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </MenuItem.Header>
                </MenuItem>

                <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource MenuItemsStyle}">
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Width="100" Text="1 File................."/>
                            <TextBlock>23 августа</TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </MenuItem.Header>
                </MenuItem>

            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

Answer (score 2):

Утро вечера мудренее) Нашел решение довольно быстро.

```
<Window.Resources>
<Style TargetType="MenuItem" x:Key="MenuItemsStyle">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="1 File................."/>
                    <TextBlock Text="23 августа" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Именно так. Общий принцип: разделяемых UI-элементов не должно быть, должны быть темплейты.